# What is default response timeout for spring-boot-starter-jetty

Tags: spring-boot, jetty

Can I know what is the default response time out and connection timeout values for 'spring-boot-starter-jetty' and how to configure them in Spring rest Application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the default values on the *ServerProperties* class:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerProperties.html

Looking at this class we can check that there is no default value:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerProperties.java#L1077

```
/**
 * Amount of time the connector will wait, after accepting a connection, for the
 * request URI line to be presented.
 */
private Duration connectionTimeout;
```

Here you can find the default Spring boot properties values:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#server-properties

If you want to set a timeout value just add the property on your application.properties file:

e.g.

```
server.jetty.connection-idle-timeout=5000
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What is the default idle time out value, If I do not set explicitly

Comment: You are welcome, I edit the answer, here you can find the default value.

Comment: Thanks juanmorshortt. Actually, in my application time out is not configured explicitly. I was searching for default time out value. I experimented by putting sleep of 5 minutes, after 5 minutes also the connection is active and client gets the response....

Comment: You are welcome, please click on the check mark if the response is correct. Regards